# Privacy Management/Account Disassociation

Tags: discussion, privacy

It seems that now the "Clear All Associations" button has been removed and there is no way to disassociate one account from another at all short of creating an entirely new OpenID (and thus having to deal with logging out and back in repeatedly). Is there a way–at all now–to disassociate accounts so that it isn't immediately obvious where someone has visited by clicking on the accounts tag?

This is more than simply a matter of controlling online brand or posting things that I don't want an employer to see.  There are some things that it is simply flat not legal for an employer to ask about, making it beneficial to both the potential employer and me that it not show up automatically. There are other things have a real potential for harassment issues outside of work

There is a solution of complete disassociation of my SE presence from my work life, but I do not consider that especially desirable either since I advocate the use of SE at work and in various social communities.  Working anonymously is *not* an adequate solution here for this same reason.  At least when there was a "Clear All Associations" button (as imperfect as it may be) there was some possibility of management of online presence, but now that it is gone there doesn't seem to be an obvious, easy mechanism for this sort of separation (at least that I've seen).

Comment: Why not just be yourself on-line and in real life. If your employer doesn't like "who you are", then either you need a different employer or need to behave better. As an employer, I would much rather employ real people than fake people.

Comment: I addressed this in my comment.  Three things: 1) This has nothing to do with my specific employer or behavior 2) As an interviewer, I'd *really* rather not even *see* anything that I am not legally allowed to ask questions about. 3) Basic boundaries: just because something is true doesn't mean that everyone in every social circle should know about it. Not everything is everybody's business.

Comment: I agree with all of those points and was mostly playing devil's advocate. I think your comment distills down your post into it's main points very well.

Comment: With respect to your point 3), if you don't want certain people to see it, you shouldn't be posting it on the Internet at all.  Eventually Google+, Facebook and their ilk will associate you to your online personas, and all that obfuscation will be for naught.